# Bashrc for Virtual Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I would like to add a command to my `.bashrc` file (or corresponding) in such a way that the command, in this case `setterm --foreground red`, is only read when I start the virtual terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1 - 6</kbd> and not the Gnome Terminal et al.

Is this possible?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
  # Stuff to do only if running in a virtual console
  setterm --foreground red
fi
```